# Twili Studio: gather_input

Tags: widget, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to design an IVR flow with Twilio Studio. When I use the gather_input widget, is there any way to not say anything? If I leave the "Text to say" field blank, the widget times out and the call gets terminated.

Comment: If you don't say anything, how will the user know what to input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (and bypass the check for empty "say" input) is to use "play" instead of "say" and provide the url of a mp3 sound file with silence. But as the remark states, you must find "another way" to let the caller know what he should input. And also he could not simply know that it is time to start typing.

As your instructions would be somehow unclear, you might want to increase eventually the timeout for DTMF gathering (to be sure the call is not cut too quickly). It is 5 seconds by default for a "gather" block.
Also, to avoid the call being cut anyway, don't forget too to connect your block to a "split" block for "user pressed key" and "user said something" and and to connect "anything" to the connector "no input" of the "gather" block.